# Display images from array, let user pick one and change image in node

Tags: javascript, arrays

OK, so, I am trying to allow a user to see a choice of images and click one to change the image in the table. The way it is currently merely adds the last image of the array. I know why this is (I think!), but struggling to find a solution. See comments. As always, all help appreciated.

```
for (r = 0; r < howOften; r++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (c = 0; c < numDays; c++) {
        col = row.insertCell(-1);
        img = new Image();
        img.src = "../www/images/TEST.png";
        col.appendChild(img); 
        img.onclick = function () {
            var myImages = new Array();
            myImages[0] = "../www/images/TEST3.png";
            myImages[1] = "../www/images/TEST4.png";
            myImages[1] = "../www/images/TEST2.png";
            for (var i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
                var allImages = new Image();
                allImages.src = myImages[i]; //I want to display this array to user somehow
                //and for them to be able to choose one and for this.src to point to that. 
                var gogetImages = allImages.src;
                this.src = (gogetImages); //I know this is wrong
            };
        };
    };
};

//LATEST VERSION STARTS FROM HERE
        function addImage (col) {
    var img = new Image();  // Note that a new img variable will be declared each time this function is called
    img.src = "../www/images/TEST.png";
    col.appendChild(img); 
    img.onclick = function () {
        var myImages = new Array();
        myImages[0] = "../www/images/TEST3.png";
        myImages[1] = "../www/images/TEST2.png";
        myImages[2] = "../www/images/TEST4.png";

        for (var i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
            var allImages = new Image();
            allImages.src=myImages[i];


            var newList = document.createElement("ul");
            var newContent = allImages;
            newList.appendChild(newContent); 
            my_div = document.getElementById("showPics");
            document.body.insertBefore(newList, my_div);
            };

            allImages.onclick = function(){

            alert("the click is working");//it is but only for the last image...grrrrr
            //this.src = ????;
            };
        };
    };

for (r = 0; r < howOften; r++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (c = 0; c < numDays; c++) {
        col = row.insertCell(-1);
        addImage(col);
    };
};
    document.getElementById('holdTable').appendChild(table);
    };
```

Comment: need to loop over images array and create( and append) a new image for each. Click handler would then change master image `src`

Comment: Hi charlietfl, I looped through the array and appended as suggested. The user can now see the  images but can't click to add. Please see edited code above. (LATEST VERSION). Thanks for your help.

Comment: need to move the `allImages.onclcik` into the `for` loop just above it so as each image is created it gets the clcik handler...  since it is after the loop only last image gets it.... might consider using jQuery for your code... could write this whole code in about 4-6 lines of code and is simpler to read

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your case,

you are using img = new Image();
Assigning a value to a variable without declaring it "with a var inside a function" creates a global variable.

So, in your code, you are creating a global "img" variable and re-assigning it to a new image which is causing problems for you.

I would suggest you to split up code into a function as below.

```
function addImage (col) {
    var img = new Image();  // Note that a new img variable will be declared each time this function is called
    img.src = "../www/images/TEST.png";
    col.appendChild(img); 
    img.onclick = function () {
        var myImages = new Array();
        myImages[0] = "../www/images/TEST3.png";
        myImages[1] = "../www/images/TEST4.png";
        myImages[1] = "../www/images/TEST2.png";
        for (var i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
            var allImages = new Image();
            allImages.src = myImages[i]; //I want to display this array to user somehow
            //and for them to be able to choose one and for this.src to point to that. 
            var gogetImages = allImages.src;
            this.src = (gogetImages); //I know this is wrong
        };
    };
}

for (r = 0; r < howOften; r++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (c = 0; c < numDays; c++) {
        col = row.insertCell(-1);
        addImage(col);
    };
};
```

Hope it works fine for you now.

Comment: Hi js, thanks for the reply. I have implemented your suggestions. However, I am still having a bit of trouble. I have managed to display the images to the user, but onclick is only working on the last image. I am also a bit unsure how to pass that to this.src/img.src.

Comment: Oh ... I missed to mention it clearly that the variables are scoped by function and not by a block (like for loop here) ... Here, `var allImages = new Image();` inside for loop does not create a new variable each time, it reuses (and overwrites) the same `allImages`

... in languages like C++, a variable declared within a `{}` block can't be accessed outside `{}` block even in the same function, in JavaScript, a variable even if declared inside a `{}` block is accessible throughout the function ... 

you can wither resolve it in the same manner I split single piece of code into a new function.

Comment: I would suggest you to go through variable scoping and anonymous functions (with immediate invocation) ... for someone new to JS, the variable scoping is one of the most confusing but most powerful feature.